# How to get images at 60 fps and imu data at 500hz at the same time with zedmini camera?

Tags: imu, mems

We know that **`IMU`** sampling rate is much higher than image taken from the sensor (**`FPS`**), so can I get images at `60FPS` and IMU data at `500hz` at the same time?

Is there an easy way? Or maybe I need to use two threads to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have two options.

**1. Bound readout from the sensor to an IMU module**

Sounds unrealistic, but some advanced **`IMU`** s, such as (no advertisements here) `InvenSense` allows to bind readings from the **`IMU`** to a sensor event (**readout**). To get familiar with the concept, please take a closer look at `FSYNC` register. You can refer to the most advanced chip: `MPU9250`.

**Quote** from the [invensense.com](https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/2-axis/idg-2020/):

> The FSYNC (Frame Sync) input allows precise timing to be achieved with Video Frame Sync at the host level for read out of the frame data.

**2. Store the last read data value**

The one you mentioned. Have a separate **producer** thread which reads the data from the **`IMU`** with required speed and puts it into the storage; and another one (**consumer**) which reads the data from the local storage.